# NSCFData fastCharacterContents crash?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am currently getting this crash log in the console:

> 2011-08-23 19:18:40.064 App[1697:707] -[__NSCFData
>    _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dbed0  2011-08-23 19:18:40.075 App[1697:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to
>       instance 0x11f1c0'

Does anyone know what this means? What could be the cause of it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object doesn't respond to a `_fastCharacterContents` selector, so there's a runtime exception being thrown.

`NSString`, however, **DOES** have a private method with that name, so it's likely that you're storing an `NSData` object into something that is assumed to be an `NSString`.