# Get CFStringRef or NSString from a "<>" format Hash data

Tags: objective-c

There is a data return from CFDictionaryGetValue like below:

```
CFDictionaryRef information;
CFStringRef value =  CFDictionaryGetValue(information,xxxx); // return a Hash code of some file
```

then the value will be `<40f42cf8 fdf07523 99a7eb6e 2fccd041 1b642e9e>`, so how can i get a string like `40f42cf8fdf0752399a7eb6e2fccd0411b642e9e` from this format data, is there any API to implement this

Comment: Almost certainly, the dictionary contains a `CFData` object, not a `CFString` for the key. Just loop through its `bytes` and print each as a 2-digit hex string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some searching, finnaly i found the solution to transfer the CFData to CFString with Hex string.

```
static CFStringRef SecCopyHexStringFromData(CFDataRef data)
{
    CFIndex ix, length;
    const UInt8 *bytes;
    CFMutableStringRef string;

    if (data) {
        length = CFDataGetLength(data);
        bytes = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
    } else {
        length = 0;
        bytes = NULL;
    }
    string = CFStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, length * 2);
    for (ix = 0; ix < length; ++ix)
        CFStringAppendFormat(string, NULL, CFSTR("%02X"), bytes[ix]);

    return string;
}
```

Thanks for `Ken Thomases`'s comments

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//copnvert CFStringRef into NSString
NSString *aNSString = (NSString *)aCFString;

NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSString *strippedReplacement = [[aNSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", strippedReplacement);
```

Comment: i use your code and also have error:*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100501480'

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
CFDictionaryRef information;
CFStringRef value =  CFDictionaryGetValue(information,xxxx);
NSString *result = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)value,CFSTR(""),kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

Comment: i use your code and have this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100210ba0'

Comment: Fix this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548961/nscfdata-fastcharactercontents-crash

Comment: Try this.. NSData *data = [result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: it is the code in the line NSString *result =........  crashed, so your new code will not be executed, can you tell me how to modify the code NSString *result =........